# Calculating size of outer/2nd-level page table

Tags: memory, operating-system, virtual-memory

Kind of a homework question but I am more trying to wrap my head around this concept:

If I have a 32bit virtual address in a two-level paging system where the page size is 8KB and the outer table has 1024 entries, how can I calculate how many bits are to represent (size of) the second level/outer page table?

The answer is supposedly 9 bits but I am unsure of how to calculate this or what the formula is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The virtual address is divided into this:

<sub>PTI - Page Table Index</sub>

```
1st PTI | 2nd PTI | Page Offset
```

The "outer page table", the first PTI, has 1024 entries. **10 bits** are needed to represent 1024 different states because `2^10 = 1024`.

The page offset has to be capable of indexing 8 KiB of bytes, therefore it is **13 bits** big. 8 KiB corresponds to 8192 different addresses and `2^13 = 8192`.

Now, the 2<sup>nd</sup> page table is left. We can calculate its size easily by subtraction:

```
32 = 10 + 13 + x  = 23 + x    | - 23
9 = x
x = 9
```

Therefore the "inner" page table can hold up to `2^9 = 512` entries.